# "Extension" of continuity of a stochastic process from $I=[0,1]$ to $I=[0,+\infty]$. Why does that happen in the below-shown way?

Tags: probability-theory, continuity, stochastic-processes, random-variables, brownian-motion

Let us pretend that we have already constructed a continuous process $B: [0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ with the same finite-dimensional distributions as a [Brownian motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process#Characterisations_of_the_Wiener_process).
Keeping in mind that a stochastic process is a family of uncountably many random variables $\omega\mapsto B(t,\omega)$ for fixed $t$,

> take a sequence $B_0\text{, }B_1\text{, }\ldots$ of independent $\mathscr{C}[0,1]$-valued random variables (i.e. *continuous* random variables on $[0,1]$) with the distribution of the Wiener process, and define $\{B(t):t\geq0\}$ by gluing together the parts, more precisely by $$B(t)=B_{\lfloor t \rfloor}(t-\lfloor t \rfloor)+\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\lfloor t \rfloor-1}B_i(1)\text{, for all }t\geq0\tag{1}$$ This defines a continuous random function $B:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ and one can see easily that this is a standard Brownian motion.

I really cannot understand the logic underpinning the passage from $\mathscr{C}[0,1]$ to $\mathscr{C}[0,+\infty]$, that is how to get from a Brownian motion on $\mathscr{C}[0,1]$ (that is, the one we pretended to have already constructed) to a Brownian motion on $\mathscr{C}[0,+\infty]$ (that is, $(1)$).

---

How to get to $(1)$ and why has $(1)$ exactly that form?

Comment: Perhaps this is just a misunderstanding of notation? The author is starting not with *one* Brownian motion but with a *sequence* of Brownian motions $B_0, B_1, \dotsc$, each defined on a 1-unit time domain. These are then glued together to make a function on $[0, \infty)$.

Comment: Oh, ok..but in which sense are they glued together? Could you please detail how one gets to $(1)$, even with an example, just to understand the logic behind that @nahp

Comment: They are "glued together" in the sense of equation (1). Imagine that you have the two "function segments" $f$ and $g$, each defined on $[0,1]$. The graph of function $f$ starts at the point $(0,f(0))$ and ends at $(1,f(1))$, and similarly with $g$. If we want the graph of $g$ to start where the graph of $f$ ends, we have to translate the graph of $g$ in the plane so that its starting point is $(1,f(1) + g(0))$ and its ending point is $(2,f(1) + g(1))$. Equation (1) effectively does this, joining the functions $B_0, B_1, \dotsc$ together in sequence, end-to-end.

Comment: Ok. Anyway, isn't it "arbitrary" in a certain sense? That is, couldn't it be as good as $(1)$ if it were (just for example) as follows: $$B(t)=B_{\lfloor t \rfloor}(t-\lfloor t \rfloor)+\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\lfloor t \rfloor-1}B_i(\color{red}{0.8})\text{, for all }t\geq0\tag{1}$$? The fact is that I cannot grasp whether $(1)$ is underpinned by a very specific and precise logic or not (that is, whether you can quite arbitrarily glue together the BM's you have or not) @nahp

Comment: There is no real "arbitrariness" that I can see in the definition of $B(t)$. In order for $B(t)$ to be continuous at 1 (for example), we should have that $B(1)$ agrees with $B_0(1)$, since $B$ will be set equal to $B_0$ on the segment $[0,1]$. But in your new equation, $B(1) = B_0(0.8)$. It turns out that this new $B(t)$ has a jump discontinuity at every positive integer (almost surely).

Comment: So far so good. But, thinking of other examples make problems arise to me. For ex., consider $t=5.8$. According to $(1)$, we will have $$B(5.8)=B_{5}(0.9)+B_0(1)+B_1(1)+B_2(1)+B_3(1)+B_4(1)$$. Why should it be that way? Why should there be a connection between the time at which $B$ is evaluated (i.e. $B(\color{red}{t})$) and the subscript of the Brownian Motions previously generated (i.e. in our example you want to evaluate $B(5.9)$ and you consider it to be equal to sum of BM'S previously generated with subscripts $0$,$1$,$2$,$3$,$4$, $5$, i.e. $B_5$ and $B_0$,$B_1$,$B_2$,$B_3$,$B_4$)

Comment: So, my question would be: why is that link necessary? $B_i$ are all independent. Couldn't $B(5.9)$ depend (for ex.) from $B_8$, $B_{24}$, $B_5$, $B_9$? Sorry, but I am not very comfortable with such things by now @nahp

Comment: Yes, you're right that you could change the names of the subscripts and obtain an equally good definition of $B(t)$. But notice that this is primarily a superficial change, because the "in-order" sequence $(B_i)_{i \geq 0}$ and the "shuffled sequence" $(B_{\sigma(i)})_{i \geq 1}$, where $\sigma$ is a bijection on $\{0,1,\dotsc\}$, have the same distribution; each is a sequence of independent Brownian motions.

Comment: It is pretty clear by now. In general. wouldn'it be more correct if author stated "$B_0$, $B_1$, $\ldots$ is a sequence of independent stochastic processes (i.e. BM's), each of them made up of $\mathscr{C}[0,1]-$valued random variables" and NOT a "sequence of independent $\mathscr{C}[0,1]-$valued random variables with Wiener distribution"? Since, by def., a Brownian Motion is a stochastic process and NOT simply a random variable. Second observation: could we summarize the logic behind $(1)$ stating that $$\text{"the sum of continuous stochastic processES is continuous as well"}$$ @nahp

Comment: Indeed, a stochastic process can be thought of as a collection of random variables, but in the case of continuous stochastic processes, you can also think of it as a *random element of the space of continuous functions*. Mathematically, this is a significant difference, but it doesn't seem important for the gluing that you've been working to understand. Your summary sounds good, but let me stress that it should feel obvious: if you glue a bunch of continuous functions together end-to-end, then the resulting function is still continuous!

Comment: Pardon, I promise it will be my last observation: I got your example on discountinuity of process $B(t)$ at $t=1$ if, for example:
$$B(t)=B_{\lfloor t \rfloor}(t-\lfloor t \rfloor)+\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\lfloor t \rfloor-1}B_i(\color{red}{0.8})\text{, for all }t\geq0\tag{1}$$
You said *"It turns out that this new B(t) has a jump discontinuity at every positive integer (almost surely)"*, but I cannot understand why. For ex., with $t=2$, it seems to me that $B(t)$ defined in $(1)$ is continuous (at $t=2$, I mean). Could you please explicit the example with $t=2$ ? Thank you a lot in advance @nahp

Comment: What I mean is that: even  drawing the "glued" function $B(t)$ with the modification in $\color{red}{\text{red}}$,  it seems to me that $$\text{problem of discontinuity of the whole function would be exclusively due to what happens in } t=1$$ and clearly this would define the entire function as a discontinuous one. However, at other integer points (e.g. $t=2$, $t=3$, etc.), with modification in $\color{red}{\text{red}}$ I would just have **an end-to-end translation with different magnitude, but not a discontinuity problem arising**. Do you agree or am I missing something important? @nahp

Comment: Okay. Plugging in $t=3$ to the red formula gives $$B(3) = B_0(0.8) + B_1(0.8) + B_2(0.8) + B_3(0).$$ However, the left-hand limit in the red formula as $t$ increases to 3 is $$\lim_{t \uparrow 3} B(t) = B_0(0.8) + B_1(0.8) + B_2(1) .$$ These are (a.s.) not equal, since $B_2(0.8) \neq B_2(1)$ a.s. I hope these comments have helped; if things are still unclear, it is probably better to move on than to get stuck here!

Comment: If you wish, you can briefly summarize all your precious hints and explanations in an answer I would be very glad to accept :) thank you for all your help, patience and time @nahp